# AngularJS Controller in route is not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a snipper of my Angular app :

### routes.js

```
angular.module("App")
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/users/:id', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/show.html',
                controller : 'UsersController',
                controllerAs : 'usCtrl'
            })
} ]);
```

### my-users-controller.js

```
(function() {
    angular.module("App")
        .controller("UsersController", ['$http', '$routeParams', 
            function($http, $routeParams) {
              alert('Hello !');
              this.user= $routeParams.id;
              console.log($routeParams.id);
        } ]);

})();
```

### show.html (this is inserted into ng-view)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
     Hello {{ usCtrl.user }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**My controller is not invoked for some reason**. When I click on my link

```
<a ng-href="#/users/john" ...
```

**routing works fine , but controller is not called** and `usCtrl.user` is not displayed. **If I use inline function for controller everything works fine.**
By inline I mean

```
...
controller : function($routeParams) {
  // code 
}
...
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: make sure you are adding my-users-controller.js file before routes.js on index.html.first check what error you are getting on console.

Comment: @saesris - no errors. controller is just not called

Comment: @Venkat no errors in the console. file is added correctly, after routes.js but controller is not called.

Comment: Are you seeing the template after the route but the user value is blank?

Comment: Did you put the controller file before the route file?

Comment: @DennisNerush nope. after. I will try to change the order, maybe that's the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the controller is never getting initialized and registered.

Verify that your build chain is pulling the file in correctly.

Then verify that controller registration is being invoked.

```
(function() {
    console.log('Controller Registered');
    angular.module("App")
        .controller("UsersController", ['$http', '$routeParams', 
            function($http, $routeParams) {
              alert('Hello !');
              this.user= $routeParams.id;
              console.log($routeParams.id);
        } ]);

})();
```

Comment: I added this and can see it - console.log('Controller Registered'); but it is not called anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module("App",[])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
       ....
} ]);
```

Your controller getting executed immediately with module  `App`  then is get overwritten by same module `App`

Comment: You have just created another app module with no dependencies. How does it solve the problem?

Comment: @DennisNerush it not going to redefine the module again.and controller is  attached to same module.So no need to DI